# Get value of one columns in DataGridView with multi select vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want get value of one columns in DataGridView  with multi select in vb.net

when I use

```
For Each cell In DGNo.SelectedCells
    If cell Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not FirstValue Then
        str += ","
    End If
    str += cell.Value.ToString
    FirstValue = False
Next
```

it take all values `DataGridView`. How get value of column(0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the individual cell values using the `DataGridView.Item` property which provides an indexer to get or set cell value in the given location.

```
DataGridView(ColumnNumber,RowNumber)
```

In your case, use it like below to get cell value from first column in first row.

```
DGNo(0,0).Value
```

To get the value of only column 0 in the selected cells,

```
For Each cell In DGNo.SelectedCells
    If cell.ColumnIndex =0 Then
        ' do work
    End If        
Next
```

Comment: i want to take all value of rows in column 0 that i selected

Comment: @AliHameed, see my edited answer. You have to clearly mention your need in the question.

Comment: but in vb.net must to edit  If cell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then and // to '